# How to use the coefficients of a Fit

Tags: probability-or-statistics

`Fit[data, {1, x}, x]` gives the least-squares adjustment of the data files through a linear function of the type $a_0 + a_1 x$. How to make reference and/or re-use  $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: Use `LinearModelFit` instead. It will directly report the parameters as `"BestFitParameters"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CoefficientList` to extract the coefficients of the polynomial you get back, i.e.

```
fitpolynomial = Fit[data,{1,x},x];
coefficients = CoefficientList[fitpolynomial,x];
```

then you can access your coefficients in the array or alternatively just write `{a0,a1}=coefficients`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
{a0, a1} = List @@ Fit[data, {1, x}, x] /. x -> 1
```

Comment: Might fail for a1=0?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yeah, it's pretty risky!

Answer (score 0):

`LinearModelFit` usage:

```
data = Table[{x, 1 - Cos[x]}, {x, -1, 1, .1}];
fit = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]
{a,b,c}=fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {0.00407547, -4.17171*10^-18, 0.462171}

```
ListPlot[data]~Show~Plot[fit[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

this does not depend on the model being a polynomial..

```
fit = LinearModelFit[data, {1,x, Cos[x],Sin[x]}, x];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {1., -1.10818*10^-15, -1., 1.34361*10^-15}